# Updating Div By Number Input

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have a number input and I want this field to update a div each time I update the number input.

By number input, I mean this:

```
<input type="number" name="year" id="year" min="2013" value="2013">
```

I added this code piece, but it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="year"]').change(function(){
   var id = this.value;
   $.getJSON('/test/' + id, function(response){
    $('myDiv').innerHTML = "dsadasdas";
    });
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

And I want the data shown inside my `myDiv` to be set from my `test` page. Which is a PHP script that executes stuff by query string. Like `/test/21` returns name of 21st person...

Thank you very much.

Comment: "does not work" HOW? Did you check for JS syntax errors? Check if the ajax call is even occuring? check if the .change() fires?

Answer (score 1):

myDiv is supposed to be an ID or a Class. Use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to alter the innerHTML value.

```
$('myDiv').innerHTML = "dsadasdas";
```

**EDIT**

It should be

```
$('#myDiv').html('dsadasdas');
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you out...

http://jsfiddle.net/4jGvf/5/

```
  $('input[name="year"]').change(function(){
     var id = $(this).val();
     var url='/test/' + id;
     alert(url);//this can be your ajax call
     $('#mydiv').html(url)
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

**HTML**

`<input type="number" name="year" id="year" min="2013" value="2013">
  <div id="result"> 
  <div>`

**JS**

```
 $('input[name="year"]').change(function(){
   var id = $(this).val();
      GetUpdate(id);               
   });
```

//change it according to your need, its for call web service written in .net

`function GetUpdate(id) {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "services/WebService1.asmx/getUpdate",
             data: '{"id":"' + id+ '"}',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
               $("#result").html(id);//write here your code for update the result

             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("error");
             }
         });
     }`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of errors in your code. Let's start from the top :

**1.** Wrong way to get the value of from the current object i.e `this`

```
var id = this.value;
```

The correct way to retrieve the value in jQuery is

```
var id = $(this).val();
```

**2.** You have an extra `});` in your code, remove the last one.

**3.** You are not using the selector properly :

```
$('myDiv').innerHTML = "dsadasdas";
```

Use either `$('.myDiv')` or `$('#myDiv')` depending on if it is a class name or an ID

**4.** jQuery has its own DOM manipulation methods like `.html()` and `.text()`, use anyone of them instead of the innerHTML method.

```
$('myDiv').html("Whatever you want..");
```

These can be the main reason why you code doesn't work. We can't write the complete code for you, so try it yourself and tell us what were the results and if possible setup a JSFiddle to demonstrate your issue.